# Can we simplified this code? show = typeof show == 'undefined' ? undefined : !show

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
function myToggle(show) {
    //...bunch of codes here...

    show = typeof show == 'undefined' ? undefined : !show
    $(el).toggleClass('d-none', show )
}
```

In above function, `show` will be inverted (boolean) only if its defined, then pass into jQuery's toggleClass(). `d-none` is a Bootstrap class to hide element.

So that when:

```
myToggle()    //this will toggle class d-none to the element
myToggle(1)   //this will remove class d-none from the element
myToggle(0)   //this will give class d-none to the element
```

So my question, can we simplified this code?

```
show = typeof show == 'undefined' ? undefined : !show
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the fact that this should be `===`, not just `==`. You almost never want `==` in JS (it's not Java or C++, always use `===` unless you *actually know why you shouldn't*). With that, you don't need a `typeof` check: just check whether your var is `undefined`, directly.

```
show = show === undefined? show : !show;
```

However, this ignores [how jQuery's .toggleClass() even works](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/). It doesn't take "true or false or undefined" as second argument, it takes a boolean, and "show" is pretty explicit in its intention, so the *real* simplication is the most obvious one:

```
show = !!show;
```

Comment: Your first code is correct. Thx for reminding the ===. I think this is the shortest solution. As for your second code, if we didn't pass the argument, it will be true instead of undefined. In jQuery, toggleClass('A', undefined) will be treated as toggleClass('A') not toggleClass('A', false)

Comment: What you're showing is called a "setter". No sir, its really a toggle. Without argument passed, it will toggle.

Comment: Sure, post updated. However, what _you_ are showing should be a setter: overloading toggles with setters was a bad API decision when jQuery introduced it a decade ago, and it's _still_ bad programming today. Either toggle (Which hasn't even needed jQuery for many years, [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) has had .add/.remove/.toggle for ages now) or explicit set the value. Don't rely on `undefined` triggering different API behaviour